# Windows 7 - Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2007, automation

Using Outlook 2007 is there a way I can have a draft email sent every Wednesday automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this directly in Outlook, but:

Task Scheduler in Windows 7 will allow you to send an e-mail at repeated intervals. It won't use Outlook but can use the same server as Outlook does for your email. For example if you use a Gmail account with outlook, it will be using the smtp.gmail.com server.

Launch Task scheduler (search for it in start menu is quickest). In the right hand column select "Create Basic Task...". Then give the action a name and click next. Define the schedule by which you want the e-mail to be sent and click next. Write the e-mail and provide The program with the outgoing mail server (this can be found under the account settings in outlook). Hope this is of use.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a third party email scheduler or you can use a task form script as show in the support microsoft link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239087

http://www.office-addins.com/-outlook-addins/email-scheduler.html